# How do I turn a vector into a specific matrix in MATLAB (example in post)

Tags: matrices, matlab, transpose

I'm currently wracking my brains on how to solve this specific situation:

I have a (20x1) vector  that looks like:

$$
H' = \begin{matrix}1&2&3&4&5& \dots & 19 & 20 
\end{matrix}
$$

I wish to turn it or reshape it into  a (4x5) matrix that looks exactly like this:

$$
H_{\mathrm{new}} = \begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15\\
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I have tried using the `reshape()` function, but it doesn't seem to be working the way I want it to. Is there a set of nested for loops I could use or some different functions to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reshape()` function fills out the matrix by column. You could build your own nested `for` loops, but you could also use `transpose()` cleverly:

`H_new = reshape(H, [5,4])’`

Note that the dimensions are swapped and the `’` is syntactic sugar for `transpose()`.

Comment: Oh, awesome! Thanks for that. That makes much more sense, and better yet the intuition is there.

Comment: Glad you find this useful. You should mark this question answered 